# FATFSというC言語のモジュールがありますが、それのアルゴリズムはわかりますか？

Tags: c, fatfs

僕は趣味でOSを作るのに挑戦しています。
今現在そのOSにファイルシステムを構築しようとしています。
言語はGCCとnaskです。
FATFSというのを参考にしようと考えているのですが、C言語についての知識はほとんどなく、
もちろんC言語を勉強しているのですが、なかなか習得できない上、作れるプログラムは
コンソールに文字列を表示するぐらいです。一応ポインタや構造体については理解しています。
そういうことでFATFSのアルゴリズムを聞きたいのです。
文章が汚く申し訳ございません。
P.S.　30日で出来るOS自作入門という本を参考にしていてOSのコアは存在します。
　　　ソースコードもひとまず理解できています。

Comment: 「FATFSのアルゴリズムを聞きたいのです。」とされていますが、説明はとても長くなるはずですので、質問を編集して、FatFSのどの部分のアルゴリズムで悩んでいるのか絞り込んだ方が良いかもしれません。巨大な回答を待ち続けるより、例えば１０個の小さな質問に分けた方が、理解が早いと思いますよ。参考：「[FATファイルシステムのしく‌​みと操作法](http://elm-chan.org/docs/fat.html)」

Answer (score 2):

OS自作入門の28-3ではFATFSのAPIを実装していると思いますが
その実装だけではよくわからないということでしょうか？

そうであれば、「Microsoft Extensible Firmware Initiative FAT32 File System Specification」がFatFSについて書かれたMicrosoftの仕様書なので参考になると思います。

しかし、これだけではよくわからないということであれば、LinuxやTOPPERSなどオープンソースの実装を眺めてみるのがよいのではないでしょうか？

https://www.toppers.jp/fatfs.html

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/fat?id=refs/tags/v3.19-rc5

OS自作入門ベースではTOPPERSのほうが参考になるかと思います。